# Image field in content type not displaying the image

Tags: media, javascript

Created a content type called Gallery and added the image style for that. The images are to be displayed in the `page--front.tpl.php`

I have fetched the images using this,

```
<div class="bannerSlider">

            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">    
                        <?php
                        $nid=11;
                        $node = node_load($nid);
                        $imgcount = count($node->field_img['und']);
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $imgcount; $i++) {
                        $image_uri = $node->field_img['und'][$i]['uri'];
                        // url
                        $masthead_raw = image_style_url('gallery-thumb', $image_uri);
                        ?>
                            <img src="<?php print $masthead_raw; ?>">           

                     <?php } ?> 
                </div>
             </div>.
```

The image is not displaying.Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert that `public://myname.jpg` to an actual URI to pass to an `img` tag

Try [image_style_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7)

Replace your code with this

```
<div class="bannerSlider">
 <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">    
    <?php
    $nid=11;
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $imgcount = count($node->field_img['und']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $imgcount; $i++) {
//$image_uri = $node->field_img['und'][$i]['uri'];
      $yourimagestylename = 'MY_IMG_STYLE';
      $image_uri = image_style_url($yourimagestylename,$node->field_img['und'][$i]['uri']);
// url
      $masthead_raw = image_style_url('gallery-thumb', $image_uri);
      ?>
      <img src="<?php print $masthead_raw; ?>">           

      <?php } ?> 
    </div>
  </div>
```